# Kali => ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm using Kali Linux to connect to a server remotely using SSH, it used to work out, but suddenly I got the message:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Even though I've added the server's IP to "hosts.allow" file.

Any Ideas?

Comment: what are the server logs? What does more verbose output of you `ssh` command look like? What exact `ssh` command are you trying? WIth what options? Too many questions and no answer.

Answer (score 1):

The message only states that the remote server does not like your connection attempt, for some unspecified reason which is left vague for obvious security reasons.

The way to diagnose that can only be to start the remote sshd process by hand,

```
    /usr/sbin/sshd -dD
```

and then try to connect, in order to see the server spewing out a lot of helpful error messages. From these it should be possible to identify the root cause of the problem.

So long as these error messages on the **server** side are missing, the info provided is *deliberately* insufficient, in order to prevent a malicious attacker from gaining any information about its penetration attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you were using the  new version of openssh client ,use the `-W option` to forward the connection.

Code would be as follows

> ProxyCommand ssh someserver -W %h:%p